# Reading label Data from MVC view using Model binders

Tags: model-view-controller, model, binders

We are having MVC view where user can select few fields.
I want to read the data from the view.
Currently using model binders I am able to read only the changeable data (from text box) into the object.
How do I read the data held in label in the view using model binders?

Answer (score 0):

Eric hexter has done this in his [opinionated input builders library](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/06/09/opinionated-input-builders-for-asp-net-mvc-using-partials-part-i.aspx). It's open source, so you could have a look there.